# use beforeEach on each test

Tags: cypress

I need to call a function `cy.restoreLocalStorage();` on each `describe` in Cypress to restore my local storage for the test:

```js
describe('Create a business rule', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    });

    it('Navigate to business rules', () => {
        cy.el('btnCompanySettings').click({ force: true });
        cy.url().should('include', 'dm/settings/general');
        cy.el('selectBreadcrumbs').click().find('.scrollable-content').children().contains('Bedrijfsregels').click();
    });
});

describe('Create a business rule', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreLocalStorage();
    });

    it('Navigate to groups', () => {
        cy.el('selectBreadcrumbs').click().find('.scrollable-content').children().contains('Groepen').click();
    });
});
```

I don't want to define this for each describe though, is it possible to define this somewhere else so it runs implicitly?

I've tried `before:spec` in my plugin file:

```js
on('before:spec', () => {
    console.log('############ BEFORE SPEC ###############');
});
```

But that only runs before the spec, not before each test.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `beforeEach()` under the `cypress/support/e2e.js` This will run the same beforeEach before all your tests.